# How to give an alias name to a schema field in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql, github-graphql

```
const Films = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'films',


  fields: () => ({
    id:{
        type: GraphQLString
      },
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString,

      },
      uniq_id: {
        type: GraphQLString,
    })
```

I want to give an alias name to the name field and fetch it with that name.

How can I do that? Please suggest............

Comment: Thank you. here it gives alias in run time. means when someone fetches in query type But I want to give an alias name through which I can fetch directly

Comment: Aliases are a client-side feature. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want two separate fields that resolve to the same value?

Comment: As you know we give some alias name in SQL query to a more readable format. Here in Films type name is a field. I want to give an alias name as first_name. So that When I fetch this field in query part I fetch it through first_name.

Comment: GraphQL is agnostic to the underlying data layer. Unless you're using something like [join-monster](https://github.com/acarl005/join-monster), it has nothing to do with SQL. If you are, you should update your question to indicate as much.

Comment: here i have not mentioned about join monster. i just want to give an alias name through which i can access it directly in query time no need to give it in that time. But i don't know whether it is possible or not??? Please tell me...